# how to add numbers of 2D array to array

Tags: java, multidimensional-array

For now, i am having 8 number of `2D array` e.g `arrayInput1` until `arrayInput8`.
So now the data from the 2D array is `1` and `0` and let set the size of the array is 25.

```
 for(int a=0; a<5; a++){
     for(int b=0; b<4; b++){
         arrayInput1[a][b] //----> The result here is 0
         arrayInput2[a][b] //----> The result here is 1
         arrayInput3[a][b] //----> The result here is 0
         arrayInput4[a][b] //----> The result here is 1
         arrayInput5[a][b] //----> The result here is 0
         arrayInput6[a][b] //----> The result here is 1
         arrayInput7[a][b] //----> The result here is 0
         arrayInput8[a][b] //----> The result here is 1
     }
 }//end of nested for loops
```

So the result from those `arraiInput` i will get `01010101`. Then I want to store them in an `array`. So the first index of `array` will print `01010101`

So the question is How to do that ?

Comment: Use a String[] and concatenate each eight of 0 or 1's into a string perhaps?

Comment: @JoakimDanielson can you show me the code ?

Comment: Did you want the result pixels to be `int`s or `String`s?

Comment: Since you have 8 2D arrays that belongs together, this is like a 3D array I assume, and the result should then be one 2D array

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a StringBuilder (or similar) to build a string from the int values and add it to a String array. I was unsure about the array sizes so I used two constants instead.

```
String[][] result = new String[ROW_SIZE][COLUMN_SIZE];
for(int a = 0; a < ROW_SIZE; a++){
   for(int b = 0; b < COLUMN_SIZE; b++){
      StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder(8);        
      builder.append(arrayInput1[a][b]);
      builder.append(arrayInput1[a][b]); 
      builder.append(arrayInput1[a][b]);
      builder.append(arrayInput2[a][b]);
      builder.append(arrayInput3[a][b]);
      builder.append(arrayInput4[a][b]);
      builder.append(arrayInput5[a][b]);
      builder.append(arrayInput6[a][b]);
      builder.append(arrayInput7[a][b]);
      builder.append(arrayInput8[a][b]);
      result[a][b] = builder.toString();
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You've got pixel data in eight bit-planes.  You want to merge these into a single plane of eight-bit integer pixels.  Here's an example of how to do it:

```
int newPixels[][] = 
    new int[arrayInput1.length][arrayInput1[0].length];

for(int a=0; a<arrayInput.length; a++){
    for(int b=0; b<arrayInput1[0].length; b++){
         newPixels[a][b] =
         arrayInput1[a][b] * 128 +
         arrayInput2[a][b] * 64 +
         arrayInput3[a][b] * 32 +
         arrayInput4[a][b] * 16 +
         arrayInput5[a][b] * 8 +
         arrayInput6[a][b] * 4 +
         arrayInput7[a][b] * 2 +
         arrayInput8[a][b];
    }
}
```

Here I've assumed that `arrayInput1` holds the bits that should become the most significant bits in the merged pixels, `arrayInput2` holds the next highest significant bits, and so on down to `arrayInput8` which holds the least significant bits.

Comment: i just want to store the `01010101` to an array. So the `array[0]` will print out `01010101`.

Answer (score 0):

You should initialize it directly :
    `int[] data = {0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1};` and `int[][] data2d = {data, data, data, data, data, data, data, data}`

Comment: i dont think is going to work. I just want to store the data like I said `01010101` into an `array`